# integral along closed curves

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. If $\int_\gamma f=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$, can we conclude $f$ holomorphic? Note that $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable, while holomorphic functions are required to be of class $C^1$.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. This result is known as [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).